# How to change the tintcolor of the slider in a MPVolumeView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, mpvolumeview

How can I change the tintcolor of the slider in a MPVolumeView? Instead of blue I want to display a different color.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to customize `UISlider`. You can do it like this:

```
[slider setMinimumTrackImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"redSlider.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

**Result:**

[image: Screenshot]

Here is some backgrounds for sliders and example image how they looks:

**Slider backgrounds:**

[image: Red slider bg]

[image: Blue slider bg]

[image: Green slider bg]

**Example:**

[image: Example]

More information [here](http://thinkitdifferently.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/customize-uislider-color/).

Answer (score 15):

After you alloc

```
volumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 145, 270, 23)];
```

Just search the MPVolumeView subviews and get the slider

```
for (id current in volumeView.subviews) {
        if ([current isKindOfClass:[UISlider class]]) {
            UISlider *volumeSlider = (UISlider *)current;   
            volumeSlider.minimumTrackTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
            volumeSlider.maximumTrackTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
}
```

Put the colors you like in UIColor and all done.
If you need to customize further, treat volumeSlider as a standard UISlider.